# Where can I insert packet content in OMNET++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

Using Omnet++ and INET framework.
I want to see the data after the transmission process with errors, noise and all channel impairments.

I found out that I can insert it in the .msg file, but it won't be affected by channel impairments.

**My question is: Where can I insert the data (packet content) to be transmitted such that I can see the effect of channel impairments on it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a packet (for example an IPv4 packet) is transmitted between two nodes via channel with some impairments, in the  destination node only the following events may occur:

1. The packet is received without errors, then link layer delivers it to the upper layers.
2. The packet is received without errors but with extended delay, then link layer delivers it to the upper layers.
3. The packet is received with error, then link layer **discards the whole packet**.

So there is no possibility that upper layer will receive the packet with errors.

Comment: Would it be theoretically possible to extend the lower layer to notify the upper layer of a reception with errors, with a different message type? It sounds like that's what they're trying to achieve, though I'm not sure it's the best way to solve this...

Comment: @Rens van der Heijden: Yes, it would be theoretically possible to notify the upper layer that a packet with incorrect CRC was received. However, when the CRC is incorrect, the lower layer doesn't know which part of the packet has an error, in particular it doesn't know whether the header contains an error or not. So the above mentioned notification is useless for the upper layer. Moreover, in many link-layer solution an ARQ mechanism organizes retransmission of an errored packet. As a consequence, after some time the upper layer will obtain the packet without errors.